# For what $m $ ,$f(x)$ does not depend on $x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$$f(x)=\frac{(3m+1)\sin x +(m+3)\cos x}{(3m+1)\cos x +(m+3)\sin  x}$$ The question is  :  for what $m$ ,f(x) does not depend of $x$?

I don't have a clue to start , can you gimme an idea ? thanks in advance .

I tried for $f'(x)=0$ to get a constant function ,but became very complicated . Is my idea true  ?

Comment: What if $m+3=3m+1$?

Comment: When $$f'(x)=0$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown :I think about it ,but is it the only solution ?

Comment: No, it isn't....

Answer (score 5):

**hint**

$$f (0)=\frac {m+3}{3m+1} $$

$$f (\frac {\pi}{2})=\frac {3m+1}{m+3} $$

$$f (\frac {\pi}{4})=1$$

Comment: Great hint +1!!

Answer (score 1):

After substitutions $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we'll get $$\frac{3m+1}{m+3}=\frac{m+3}{3m+1},$$
which gives $m=1$ or $m=-1$.

Easy to see that both values are valid.

Comment: thank you . what about $f'=0$ when we want to solve rather than tricky way ?

Comment: @Khosrotash I can post a solution by derivatives if you want (say it only), but I think my solution is much more shorter.

Comment: The derivative gives $(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)((3m+1)^2-(m+3)^2)=0$ and we get the same result.